# C# OpenXml Selective Font Bolding

Tags: c#, fonts, ms-word, openxml

I have a function that takes a couple of font parameters, and produces the required font in a RunProperties class. How can I turn on/off the Bold class? MSDN was pretty useless on this issue.

```
public RunProperties getRCFont(int size, string color = "000000", string font = "Futura Bk BT", bool bld = false, bool und = false) {

    return new RunProperties(new Bold() { Val = bld ? OnOffOnlyValues.On : OnOffOnlyValues.Off });

}
```

This doesn't work, produces this error:

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.OnOffOnlyValues' to 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OnOffValue'

But OnOffValue class has no properties!!

P.S. : Underline class has UnderlineValues class, but not for the Bold class (such as BoldValues), bah.

Edit - I'm sorry I got it. For anyone interested in the solution:

```
return new RunProperties(new Bold() { Val = bld ? new OnOffValue { Value = true } : new OnOffValue { Value = false } });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RunProperties(new Bold() { Val = bld ? new OnOffValue { Value = true } : new OnOffValue { Value = false } });
```

Comment: Another (shorter) way to write this:
RunProperties(new Bold() { Val = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(bld) } );

Answer (score 0):

You can resume the line using bld instead of use the operator "?:"

RunProperties(new Bold() { Val =  new OnOffValue { Value = bld } });